# Prevent an android activity to go pause state when HOME button is pressed

Tags: java, android, wear-os

While using an editor activity I will prevent a HOME button press. But...
I have tried Key events catching up on activity nothing hits there. also tried onUserLeaveHint() to show a confirmation dialog.

I started activity like following

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, A.class);    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, "EDITOR");
```

any idea what could be a good practice to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by preventing an activity to go to `Pause` state when pressed Home button ?

Comment: I have an editor fragment on that activity which will show a confirmation alert to user in wearos when hardware HOME button is pressed. so I am wondering what could be the best practice to achieve this,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to do, you cannot override Home button press and hence you cannot prevent your activity to go to in pause state.
actually it goes to stop state when you click on home. first pause and then stop.